# Published Beta App Opt-in Link not Working

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I created an Open Track Beta release a few days ago for the first time, which has shows up as published since yesterday on Google Play Console. However if I click the 'View on Google Play' button it returns 'Not Found' and when I follow the opt-in link, I get an error that it isn't available even though I'm logged in as the creator of the app:

[image: App not Available]

I do have the option of releasing it to production, which I assume would work, but would prefer to have a working testing release first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add yourself as a tester, to test the app. So open beta channel click the Manage Testers and add the mail that you use as google play account at your phone.

But I suggest you use **internal test channel** for this. Beta is mostly used for the apps already released and it is open testing.

So open internal test channel, add your apk and add yourself as a tester by clicking Manage Testers and adding your email (the mail you use as google play store account at your phone), share yourself the opt-link which you got from internal test instead of beta.

Then you will have early access, so you can download it from play store easily

Comment: I was able to successfully create an internal test channel and after a while the beta version began working as well